# How to display checkboxes checked based on user selection

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have 10 checkboxes say name ,age ,sex ,fname , lname etc.
suppose user selected fname and then lname and saves the preferences to see result in ui-grid.now when he comes back to this page he should see the check boxes in this order - fname,lname,name,age ,sex etc. and fname,lname should be checked. How can I achieve this using java script or angularjs

Comment: Could you please elaborate your problem statement with code if you have tried so far, so that we can give you better solution...

Comment: show code so can know what you want

Answer (score 0):

little advice

1. i think you need a queue where you can save the order of your checkboxes
2. You could use the Local Storage, Cache Storage, or Cookies to save which checkbox were marked